# On google sheets, how to make it so when I type in a number, it highlights that number elsewhere on that sheet in a designated area

Tags: google-sheets

I make a daily truck list for my work.  In the green (B) box is the list of trucks I can use, in the red (A) column is where I type in the truck number slated to be used for that route.  How can I make it so when I type in the truck in the red (A) column, it automatically highlights that matching truck number in the green (B) box?  And only in that that designated green box.

Bonus if there's a way to highlight the B box a different color if a truck gets listed more than once.

[image: LIST EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

Of course, this task is easiest to solve using conditional formatting.

Select the range **A57:H64** (first of your "green range") and [**choose Format and then Conditional formatting**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en).

Select **Custom Formula is** and enter `=COUNTIF($J$2:$J$56,A57)=1`. Here **$J$2:$J$56** is your "red area" and **A57** is the top left cell of the range to be formatted. Choose a fill color, for example green.

[image: Format 1]

Click **Add another rule**, change **1** in formula to **2** (`=COUNTIF($J$2:$J$56,A57)=2`) and choose another color, for example orange.

Click **Add another rule**, change **=2** in formula to **>2** (`=COUNTIF($J$2:$J$56,A57)>2`) and choose another color, for example red.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.  I did what you said, but it will only reflect the conditional formatting in column A only, it will not do B-H.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C6NoLFGvMsOXZnAruy3Y0STLmad4lZlyv9q1JHn3pm8

I tried on another sheet and made the formatting for each column, which works.. but something weird is happening (example: if I try typing 183 into J2-J6, it will not conditionally format.  But if I enter 183 in any other space below those, then it works.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Swq_o0lhyWiCi9FeeXrzBPbcIXptrgzt62AUayY7sLo

Comment: Thank you for providing access to the tables. When preparing the answer, I was so focused on transferring the data structure from your screenshot to my test table as accurately as possible that I made a mistake: I used a relative reference **J1:J56** instead of an absolute one **$J$2:$J$56** in the formula. I have now corrected the formulas in my answer and in your [**TESTER table**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C6NoLFGvMsOXZnAruy3Y0STLmad4lZlyv9q1JHn3pm8/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Perfection!  You are a legend my friend.  Thank you very much.